# Data creation via BAPI is intermittently inoperative despite committing updates

Tags: abap, bapi

I have the following case:

I'm creating transports documents in a LOOP (using BAPI_CREATE). After this loop, if everything is fine, I call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT (and wait = 'X').

After that, I do another loop for the created transports to change them. But not everytime I can change the first transport (the LAST created). Could it be because that commit work has not been performed properly at all? I used WAIT UP TO 3 SECONDS before the second loop, and it worked; but I would find out the real problem and how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: why not just to wait 3 seconds and not have any headache? I suppose time lag is too small and you don't have any other choice

Comment: please give more precise details. BAPI_CREATE doesn't exist. Which BAPI do you then use to change the transports? Which error messages do you get?

Comment: I can't say anything certain based on information you provided. My guess is: the BAPI you are using starts an asynchronous process (basically creation process starts, but your program continues and does not wait for it to finish) and as a result, you might sometimes have it created and but not at others. If that is the cause there is no universal solution. You somehow have to check if records are created before you start processing.

Answer (score 0):

These are different processes, even with commit and wait.

try to experiment with

```
SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL.
```